# Juggling multiple UINavigationControllers using the App Delegate and ensuring UINavigationController correctly deallocs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I have a app which uses two UINavigationControllers - one for the menu system and one for the actual game. A common UINavigationController is declared in my appDelegate. When the app loads, it either loads the Menu or the Game's UINavigationController. And of course the player can then navigate between the two.

When going from the menu to the game, I create a new UINavigationController and present it as follows:

```
    GameViewController *rootController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
     [rootController release]; 
     newNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
     [self presentModalViewController:newNavController animated:YES];
[newNavController release];
```

However, I've noticed that when I do this, the Menu's viewController never calls dealloc. Presumably because there's still a reference to something keeping it alive. I've found that when I explicitly set the App Delegate's UINavigationController to the new navigation controller, (before releasing the new navController) it releases the Menu. I do this as follows:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
 appDelegate.navController = newNavController;
 [newNavController release];
```

Is this good practice? I've found that when navigating from the game back to the menu however, the same trick doesn't seem to work. I.e.

```
MainMenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init]; 
 UINavigationController *newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
 [menuViewController release];
 newNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
 [self presentModalViewController:newNavController animated:YES];

 //Setting the appDelegate's navController to the new navController allows the menu to dealloc. 
 //This must happen AFTER the newNavController has been loaded. 
 MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
 appDelegate.navController = newNavController;
 [newNavController release];
```

never call's dealloc on the game's main ViewController. And when I navigate back to the game again, the menu's main ViewController is no longer released either.

Am I missing something when juggling UINavigationControllers?

Thank you,

Michael

EDIT: I've since realised that the reason my game's main ViewController was not deallocing, was because I has some NSTimers that I hadn't invalidated! However, I'm still curious to know if my above approach is correct, and that explicitly redefining the navController in the App Delegate is the correct way to allow the different UINavigationControllers to dealloc :)

Comment: I'm puzzled by a few things: 1) If your app is a game, why would you ever want to deallocate the game's view controller? 2) As a corollary, why are you presenting the game controller modally? 3) What is the view controller you're using to present the game and menu controllers (i.e., what is the class of `self` in your example code, and what role does that object play in your app)?

Comment: 1. Well it's a rather simple game, and the user may flip back and forth between menu and game, so I figured it would just be good practice to unload the game when they enter the menu. 2. I'm not sure how else to present the game controller to make it flip around nicely. I could add it as a subview of the window, but then it just changes suddenly and I like the transition. Is this bad practice? 3)The self in my code is the rootViewController of the current UINavigationController. Is that bad :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your life easier. Use a single UINavigationController, and maintain two separate View Controller stacks, which are just arrays of UIViewControllers. You can use `[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]` to just swap the stacks out and leave the nav controller in place. Use `UINavigationController.viewControllers` to get the current stack to hold onto before replacing it. It's something like 14.3 billion times easier and cleaner than dealing with all the vagaries of multiple nav controllers.

Comment: Where should I do the switch - in the app delegate?